# CV errors in graduate application

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

What errors do applicants make in their CV while applying to US graduate programs, apart from obvious errors like spelling, grammar, formatting etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE! On this forum we discourage "list" questions such as this one. Check out [help/on-topic] site to see what we tend to look for... we want questions to be more directly answerable, rather than just lists of information.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some that I encounter

1. **Listing all of your achievements, rather than your notable ones**. No one cares that you got 3rd place in a high-school biology competition. List things that are truly outstanding, not minor stuff.
2. **Not selecting referees carefully** - make sure that the reference letter writers you pick actually like you and would write positive letters. In particular, many universities would largely disregard reference letters from lecturers you took a class with. Unless there was some special relationship (a joint project, a really outstanding performance in class), the letter amounts to 'this student attended my class, and got a good grade'; this is information that I can get reading your transcript.
3. **Writing unqualified achievements**. I'm not talking about outright lying (obviously don't), but more things like "talented writer". Ok, you're a talented writer - how about some evidence to back it up? Did you win any competitions? Did your work get published anywhere?
4. CV sections not ordered according to importance: when someone reads your CV, they're probably reading at least 50 more that day. I don't need to wade through unimportant information (languages you speak comes to mind) before I get to what I want to know. Think - what would make a person pick **me** out of the bunch? Write that first.

Comment: *In particular, many universities would largely disregard reference letters from lecturers you took a class with.* --- This part seems extremely strange to me (the rest of what you said seems fine), but maybe by "lecturer" you specifically mean a very low-level teacher (e.g. graduate T.A., post-doc, visiting faculty, etc.) rather than a tenure-track or tenured faculty member. Maybe this is also somewhat field-dependent, since in mathematics (especially pure mathematics) a candidate's teachers are pretty much the only people who could write such letters.

Comment: While I certainly can't attest to what happens in other disciplines (or in other departments!), this is certainly true from what I encountered, and from speaking to colleagues in my field. I can also say this from the pool of letters I had to read. Generally letters from lecturers who don't know the student tend to be generic and uninformative.

Comment: *letters from lecturers who don't know the student* --- I don't think anyone would disagree with this, but you did not originally have "who don't know the student". For what it's worth, I don't recall anyone during my undergraduate or graduate years using anyone except a course teacher for a reference, but this was before [REU summer research](http://www.ams.org/programs/students/emp-reu) and other opportunities (such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budapest_Semesters_in_Mathematics)) were generally available in math. (BTW, I originally upvoted your answer.)

Comment: *(BTW, I originally upvoted your answer.)* --- Looking at this the next day, it seems to suggest that I upvoted your answer and then canceled my upvote at a later time. What I meant is that when I originally read your answer, I upvoted it because, as I said in my first comment, "the rest of what you said seems fine" (and I have not canceled my upvote).